# Modelling longitudinal data using cross sectional data

Tags: panel-data, cross-section

I only have access to cross sectional data (surveys taken at one date after variable days after exposure). I want to show the relationship between the days after exposure and the survey measure but am unable to get longitudinal data. Is there an example someone has published on this? I thought of stratifying time from the exposure and then adjusting for characteristics (age, gender etc) across groups but did not find a study where this has been published. Can anyone help?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You seem to understand that your data can't answer your question. But your asking for citations of papers using the wrong data for a similar analysis to the one you'd like to do, even when you know it's biased?

Comment: Unfortunately it was a commercial requirement, so I was looking to make it as unbiased as possible, realising that it was not ideal!